# Change SQL database Timezone of Microsoft Azure Mobile Service in coding

Tags: sql-server, azure

As far as I know , Microsoft is not providing a option to change Azure SQL database timezone. Its set to UTC default. I need to change Time zone in code.

I am using a query `SELECT * from Offers WHERE expirydate< getdate()"` to fetch all offers which is expired. I need to do that according to Indian Standard Time. Is there any way to do it  Programmatically (My backend is in Javascript)

Comment: TODATETIMEOFFSET - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630335.aspx